# How do I insert insert into a map of <string, vector<pair:: <string, string>> > in C++?

Tags: c++11, vector, dictionary, std-pair

I am trying to create a symbol table where the key to the map is an identifier and the vector it returns contains pairs of strings representing type and scope, respectively. I am able to get a map with a string key return a vector of single strings to work, but when I try pairs, I get an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std; //using std namespace for readibility for this question

int main() {
    string key = "myKey";
    string string1 = "string1";
    string string2 = "string2";
    pair <string, string> stringPair = make_pair (string1, string2);

    map<string, vector<std::pair <string, string>>> myMap;
    myMap.insert( make_pair (key,  make_pair (string1, string2) )); //insert key into map, create empty vector
                                    //this is where I get th error

    myMap[key].push_back(std::make_pair (string1, string2) ); //use key, push strings into vector<string, string>

    return 0;
}
```

`error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert(std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&'`

I could get a vector of single strings to work, but that seems like more of a workaround than having true pairs for each instance of an identifier. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to insert a pair into the map, instead of a vector of pairs.   If you want the vectors to start empty, the easiest way is to let it use the default constructor (which for a vector, makes an empty vector), and not explicitly insert into the map at all:

```
map<string, vector<std::pair <string, string>>> myMap;
myMap[key].push_back(std::make_pair (string1, string2) ); //use key, push strings into vector<string, string>
```

Comment: Oh, I see my error now. But I still need to insert explicitly to put the key in the map, right?

Comment: No, `map::operator[]` constructs a default value and inserts it if the key was not in the map previously.  Since `vector::vector()` (the default ctor) gives an empty vector, that's exactly what you want.

Comment: Ok, I've got that working. On final question, if you would. How do I access the members in the vector pair? `it->first` refers to the key, but `it->second.first` doesn't work.

Comment: `it->second` is the vector.  So `it->second[0].first` would be the first string in the first element of the vector

Comment: @Johnny that's why you should use helper variables with meaningful names: `auto const& thevector = it->second; auto const& thepair = thevector[0]; auto const& thestring = thepair.first;` (Of course there are better, semantic names). You don't *have* to break it up that far, but `it->second[0].first` is (obviously from your question) very obfuscating and hard to get your head around. iow: if it's hard to write, it's harder to read and maintain, so make it easier.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very simple C++11 version that work but might be hard to read later, depends on the people:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std; //using std namespace for readibility for this question

int main() {
    string key = "myKey";
    string string1 = "string1";
    string string2 = "string2";
    map<string, vector<std::pair <string, string>>> myMap;

    myMap.insert( { key, {{ string1, string2 }} } ); 

    return 0;
}
```

Tested there: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ (GCC4.8)

Of course if you want to add to the vector that contain the strings, you need to first check if the vector already exists. Here I am not checking if the vector already exists so if it does, there will be no insersion.